# Android: ListView Multiple Choice not working

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

When user selects an item/row in list view, it should be selected/highlighted in a certain color (eg. background color should change).

In my **MyActivity.xml**:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linlay1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/myblackimage" >
...
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listview1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:choiceMode="multipleChoice" 
                 android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" 
                 android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector">
            </ListView>
...
```

**list_item_selector.xml**

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" android:state_activated="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

</selector>
```

**item.xml** This is used a item/row in the listview (i think this is what should change background color in response to selection)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="itemPicked"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="5dp" >

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_orderno"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_ordername"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java :**

```
private MyAdapter myAdt;
private ArrayList myArrayList;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
ListView myListView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
...
myAdt = new MyAdapter(this, myArrayList);
myListView1.setAdapter(myAdt);
...
}
```

When i click on item/row on the list view, the row does not change color at all.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you add the item layout?

Comment: quinnjn> added item.xml in question - kindly see... thanks

Comment: hmmm i had the same problem ... i did resolve it by implementing a [Checkable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Checkable.html) interface and using this class as root of row layout(by making CheckableXXXXLayout class) there should be sample application in sample's folder of the SDK (CustomChoiceList or something)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess problem is in **list_item_selector.xml**
note that default and pressed states have the same drawable background

```
<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray"/>

<item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
```

make them different and also add one more state selected, something like this

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:exitFadeDuration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime">

        <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/darker_gray" android:state_selected="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" android:state_activated="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light"/>

</selector>
```

*just in case this will not work remove state_activated*

besides all above remove this line from my_activity.xml (also make sure you have all lowcase letters in xml nam)

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector"
```

and add this line to root item of your item.xml

```
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector"
```

so it looks like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:onClick="itemPicked"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/list_item_selector" >
```

Comment: This did not help... :(

Comment: even after you remove <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_light" android:state_activated="true"/> ?

Comment: yes even after removing the state_activated thing... pls see item.xml - this is the layout of individual row of the listview - i guess this might where the issue is.

Comment: please try new answer (actually add last changes)

Comment: strange, check if your list items actually getting focused when you press on them, if they don't check which item steals focus and make it focusable=false, if this will not help either then there is a something obvious that I don't see

Comment: Vilen M> Yes your suggestion is working fine! I also had to add this line in itemPicked(View view) method: view.setItemChecked(position , true); You may want to verify and add this to your answer for completeness.

Comment: For me, the only one that got picked up was state_activated. Neither state_checked, not state_selected seemed to get picked up. @Jasper not sure where your itemPicked method was meant to go, but I seemed to get it to work without it. Perhaps if I had used that then state_checked would have worked